# binarize input for pytorch

Tags: input, binary, loader, pytorch

may I ask how to make data loaded in pytorch become binarized once it is loaded? 
Like Tensorflow can done this through:

```
train_data  = mnist.input_data.read_data_sets(data_directory, one_hot=True)
```

How can pytorch achieve the `one_hot=True` effect.

The data_loader I have now is:

```
torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.FloatTensor')
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        datasets.MNIST('data/', train=True, download=True,
                       transform=transforms.Compose([
                         # transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                           transforms.ToTensor()])),
        batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
```

I want to make data in train_loader be binarized. 
Now what I am doing is: After loading the data,

```
for data,_ in train_loader:
    torch.round(data) 
    data = Variable(data)
```

Use the `torch.round()` function. Is this correct?

Comment: there is no function in pytorch library. can you provide what you are expecting and what you have? we will be able to help you then.

Comment: Edited. Is the edit help~? Because I am calculating binary cross entropy loss (nn.BCELoss()). In pytorch.org, this is done by pass sigmoid(x). I was wondering if I can make the x be binary in the first place. Will make the input image binarized during it is inputed, make difference to neural network~?

Comment: first of all, i don't understand what do you mean by binarized input? you have image data which represents pixel values. so, why you need to binarize the input is not clear to me. moreover, how `sigmoid(x)` is related to binarizing? can you define the binarization first? also, edit your question to clearly explain what do you have now and what you want.

Comment: Oh, it is like  binaryzation/thresholding. I.e. make the input image's pixel value to 0 and 1 only, which looks only black and white. [link](http://felixniklas.com/imageprocessing/binarization). Sigmoid output number between 0-1, which nn.BCSLoss() take in number between 0-1, using sigmoid is what the pythorch doc said.

Comment: You should specify how exactly do you want to binarize your input image, by some threshold (pixel value below 128 set to 0 and above set to 1, for example, ) or something else? Currently, it is missing in your post, which makes your question difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one-hot encoding idea is used for classification. It sounds like you are trying to create an autoencoder perhaps.

If you are creating an autoencoder then there is no need to round as BCELoss can handle values between 0 and 1. Note when training it is better not to apply the sigmoid and instead to use [BCELossWithLogits](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) as it provides numerical stability.

Here is an example of an [autoencoder](https://github.com/GunhoChoi/Kind-PyTorch-Tutorial/tree/master/06_Autoencoder_Model_Save) with MNIST

If instead you are attempting to do classifcation then there is no need for a one hot vector, you simply output the number of neurons equal to the number of classes i.e for MNIST output 10 neurons and then pass it to [CrossEntropyLoss](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) along with a LongTensor with corresponding expected class values

Here is an example of [classification](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html) on MNIST